# Casting a Collection<T> to an interface - why isn't it working?

Tags: c#, collections, casting

Can someone explain why the below code throws the following exception:

`InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection'1[UserQuery+Test]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection'1[UserQuery+ITest]'.`

```
public interface ITest
{
}

public class Test : ITest
{
}

void Main()
{
  Collection<Test> t = new Collection<Test>();
  t.Add(new UserQuery.Test());
  var casted = (Collection<ITest>)t.Cast<ITest>();
}
```

The signature for `Cast<T>` implies `T` is output, but it isn't. What is going on? Does `covariance` have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 6):

When you use `Enumerable.Cast<T>`, you're creating a new `IEnumerable<T>`, not just "casting" in the traditional sense of a cast.

As such, the collection returned is no longer a `Collection<T>`, but rather an internal (non-public) implementation of `IEnumerable<ITest>`.

Comment: Well, it may or may not create a `new IEnumerable<T>`. It's optimized not to if it doesn't have to. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet Very true - but its safer to assume that it's not going to be the same collection type you're passing in...

Comment: It's safer to assume either could happen - operations on the result could affect the source or not, so either way has dangers to bad assumptions.

Comment: @JonHanna How does assuming that you have to treat it as `IEnumerable<T>` lead to bad assumptions?  If you assume its `IEnumerable<T>`, you're going to be using it as read-only/enumerate-only, which should always be the safer assumption here...  (There is no way, given that interface, to operate on the collection.)

Comment: @Reed I wouldn't assume anything. Assuming it is a different collection will bite you if you think you can enumerate over it and change the collection, because if it is the same collection, you'll get an exception when attempting that.

Comment: There's no promise other methods won't cast it up to something that is directly mutable as another optimisation (AFAIK, nothing in System.Linq.Enumerable does, but something could - it's a reasonable optimisation).

Answer (score 1):

Casting is unnecessary.
You can create a Collection so you don't need to cast:

```
void Main()
{
  Collection<ITest> t = new Collection<ITest>();
  t.Add(new UserQuery.Test());
}
```